# update delete listview items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview that when clicked opens up but doesnt display detailed information about that list view item. The data for the listview is entered in by a class into a sqlite datase and pulled from a sqlite database by another class. Not sure where I went wrong with the class the should pul the data when a list viewitem is clicked. I do not have enough pont to post imaged of the related xml files but the onClick methods are below

Listview:

@Override

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked on :" + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent updateDeleteLoginInfo = new Intent (this, UpdateDeleteLoginList.class);

    LoginDetails clickedObject = loginArrayList.get(arg2);

        Bundle loginBundle = new Bundle();
    loginBundle.putString("clickedwebSite",clickedObject.getsName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedwebAddress",clickedObject.getwUrl());
    loginBundle.putString("clickeduserName",clickedObject.getuName());
    loginBundle.putString("clickedpassWord",clickedObject.getpWord());

    updateDeleteLoginInfo.putExtras(loginBundle);

    startActivity(updateDeleteLoginInfo);
```

Update Class:

@Override

```
public void onClick(View v){

    loginSitetext = sName.getText().toString();
    loginAddresstext = wUrl.getText().toString();
    loginUsertext = uName.getText().toString();
    loginpassWordtext = pWord.getText().toString();

    LoginDetails loginDetails = new LoginDetails();

    loginDetails.setsName(bundledWebSite);
    loginDetails.setwUrl(bundledWebAddress);
    loginDetails.setuName(bundledUserName);
    loginDetails.setpWord(bundledPassWord);

    if(v.getId()==R.id.rucBttn){
        finish();

    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.ruuBttn){
        updateLoginDetails(loginDetails);

    }else if(v.getId()==R.id.rudBttn){
        deleteLoginDetails(loginDetails);
    }

}


private void updateLoginDetails(LoginDetails loginDetails){

    dataStore androidOpenDbHelper = new dataStore(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE, loginSitetext);
    contentValues.put(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_ADDRESS, loginAddresstext);
    contentValues.put(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME, loginUsertext);
    contentValues.put(dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD, loginpassWordtext);

    String[] whereClauseArgument = new String[1];
    whereClauseArgument[0]= loginDetails.getsName();

    System.out.println("whereClauseArgument[0] is :" + whereClauseArgument[0]);

    sqliteDatabase.update(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE, contentValues, dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE+"=?", whereClauseArgument);

    sqliteDatabase.close();
    finish();
}

private void deleteLoginDetails(LoginDetails deleteLoginDetails){

    dataStore androidOpenDbHelper = new dataStore(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = androidOpenDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    String[] whereClauseArgument = new String[1];
    whereClauseArgument[0] = deleteLoginDetails.getsName();

    sqliteDatabase.delete(dataStore.TABLE_NAME_INFOTABLE,dataStore.COLUMN_NAME_SITE+"=?", whereClauseArgument);

    sqliteDatabase.close();
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the 'C' in whereClauseArgument in another class was not capatalized. After capitalizing it every thing worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

you can use notifyDataSetChanged() function to achive updating the listView.

or

assign a new adapter evrytime you update list that needs  updating.

Comment: Im sorry, the issue I am having is that once a ListView item is clicked, the activity that used to Update/Delete is not populated with the detailed information of the click ListView item.